# Where I am making mistake in the following matlab programme for cdf?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, if-statement, probability-density

I have written a following code :

```
mu = mean(20x1) ;sigma =std(20x1) ;x = temp value (300x1); y1 = zeros(size(x)); 
y2 = zeros(size(x)); z = zeros(size(x));  p = zeros(size(x));
for k = 1:length(x)
             for j=1:length(mu)
      if x(k) > mu(j)
           z(k) =x(j);
          y1=cdf('normal',z,mu(j),sigma(j),'upper');
      elseif x(k)< mu(j)
          p =x(k);
         y2 = cdf('normal',p,mu(j),sigma(j),'lower');
        end
    end
end
```

Now in this programme I am comparing whether my 'x' value is greater or less than the calculated mean value or not. If x>mu then I am storing all those x value in 'z' and with that z value I am trying to calculate y1. Similarly if x < mu value than those x value stored in p and with this p value I am trying to calculate y2 value.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. So delete your old identical question. By the way you already got an answer : `y1 = cdf('normal',x(x>mu),mu,sigma,'upper')`

Comment: and your mu is a single variable of course your code will crash if you try to access to mu(2)...

Comment: No I don't hence I posted my question entire code here. Don't be rude so much

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you simply want:

```
z1 = x(x>mu);
y1 = cdf('normal',z1,mu,sigma,'upper');
z2 = x(x<mu);
y2 = cdf('normal',z2,mu,sigma,'lower');
```

Comment: yes correct this is what I want , I did the same for single value but when I am going to deal with x (whose value is 300) and mu and sigma(whose value is (20) then I am not able to get my y1 and y2 value for each x value

Comment: @Neha by value you mean length ? so if I understand you have 1 array x that contains 300 values, and an array mu and sigma that contain 20 values ? and you want to test all the pairs of mu and sigma for the same x array ?

Comment: I have size of data of 300 (length). Yes you are right. Yes mu and sigma contains only 20 values. And yes I want to test my all values with all pairs of mu and sigma.  So let us assume that only 5 value of x satisfied x<mu condition than I want to know those value and at the same time I also want to know its corresponding y1 value